# FoxPro 9.0 How to loop through a program

Tags: foxpro

I have an assignment to loop through a single column table "contracts", and for each loop call a program "MyProgram" using the values from contracts. And finally present the results in a table for all loops.

```
Indata:
=================
Contracts.dbf
=================
P01
C04
CH45
T31

Result:
===========================
ResultFile.dbf
===========================
P01   C04    CH45     T31
---------------------------
100    11    302     -872
9.63   0     45.2     342
```

The values for each contract is generated in MyProgram that takes in contract as an argument and generate a column of results with same contract as title. So using MyProgram for contract P01 give

```
======
P01
------
100
9.63
```

So far my program looks like

```
SELECT distinct contract FROM bs_case
COPY TO contracts.dbf
    NbContracts =RECCOUNT()
    CLOSE TABLES

counter  = 1

DO WHILE counter < NbContracts
    && calling MyProgram ()
    counter = counter + 1
ENDDO
```

I haven't been able to extract contract name from "Contracts.dbf" and don't really know how to create the final result file "ResultFile.dbf"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's pseudo but should work:

```
******
SELECT 0
CREATE CURSOR MyResults ( columnName C(10), value1 I, value2 N(8,2) )  &&Result cursor
SELECT contracts
LOCATE   &&Go to top of file.
SCAN     &&start loop
     =MyProgram(FIELD(1), contracts.ColumnName)  &&Pass name of column and it's value
ENDSCAN

SELECT MyResults  &&View results.
BROWSE LAST NORMAL

PROCEDURE MyProgram(fieldname, value1)
    ***Do stuff to
    ***generate calculatedvalue1 and calculatedvalue2

    ***Insert name of column, value1 and value2
    INSERT INTO MyResults (columnName, value1, value2) ;
        VALUES(fieldname, calculatedvalue1, calculatedvalue2)
END PROC
```

Comment: Its working great! Is there a way to have MyResults with generic number of rows?

Comment: In foxpro, each row number can be retrieved with the ?RECNO(). So you could do: SELECT RECNO() as rownum, * FROM MyResults INTO CURSOR MyResults. Or create an AUTOINC column when defining the cursor. CREATE CURSOR MyResults (myField i AUTOINC NEXTVALUE 1 STEP 1, myfield2 C(10), etc...). Be sure to mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: Hi, I was a bit hasty with my reply. After the first loop, my procedure don't pick up the second value of the row C04. The Field() gives the field name, and I only have one field contract. How do I get the values from each row by iterating? Using RECNO() gives the the row number but I want the content of the row and not the row number

Comment: if you table is "Contracts" and your field/column is named "contract", then doing this will give you the value of the current row: x = contracts.contract. "x" will contain the value of the column. So in the MyProgram procedure, "value1" contains the value you are looking for.